# What does -[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001c0360 mean

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nsurl

I've been trying to get some example code interfaced with a Cocoa interface(It had been written using Carbon); however, when I attempted to replace

```
 err = ExtAudioFileCreateNew(&inParentDirectory, inFileName, kAudioFileM4AType, inASBD, NULL, &fOutputAudioFile);
```

with

```
err = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(CFURLCreateWithString(NULL,(CFStringRef)inFileName,NULL),kAudioFileM4AType,inASBD, NULL,kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &fOutputAudioFile);
```

I started to get these exceptions

> 2011-09-25 10:27:31.701 tester[1120:a0f] -[NSURL length]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x1001c0360
>       2011-09-25 10:27:31.701 tester[1120:a0f] -[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001c0360.

I've looked at several other questions and answers and in all of those cases the problem was related to a `NSURL` being passed when a `NSString` was expected; however, I can't find where/if I'm doing that. I've looked at the documentation and as far as I can tell with my extremely limited knowledge of Apple's APIs. I'm not doing anything wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us your declaration and assignment of `inFileName`?

Comment: I'd be glad to, but it's a bit complicated, It's declared here CFStringRef FilePath= (CFStringRef)[oPanel URL];

Comment: That `-URL` method looks suspiciously like a method that’d return an `NSURL/CFURLRef` instead of an `NSString/CFStringRef`. Try to use the return value of that method directly in `ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL()` without creating another URL.

Comment: @Bavarious Thank you, that seems to have been it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. `NSURL` class does not have a `-length` instance method.

Have you tried to create the `NSURL` object with Objective-C syntax and cast it to `CFURLRef`?

Comment: I was having a similar issue. `[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURLAsString]]];` can throw the same exception if the URL uses the assets-library scheme. Something internally is trying an ill-advised length invocation, it would seem.

Answer (score 11):

May be help you, i had same problem

I was trying to make `UIImage` from :

```
[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]]];
```

Then its solved with by making string with `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`

```
NSString *urlStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_photosURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: This solves the problem. I was going crazy. Thank you

Comment: This fixed my crashing issue from a perfectly fine url string.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while getting url from string like 
`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Activity/GetBudget/%@",self.baseURL,activityID]`

and I resolved it by calling `absoluteString`

like this

`[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Activity/GetBudget/%@",self.baseURL,activityID] absoluteString]`